# Where can I find a simple and useful list of VBA objects and methods for a beginner?

Tags: vbe

I tried pressing f2 to get the VBE thingo open and it just looks like jibberish to me.

I need something nice and simple which gives me a heirachy of what key words to use and where to put the dots so that I can do what I need to do and start learning this lanauge.

h = Worksheets("name_lists").range("g17").Offset(down, 0).Value

I don't know what worksheet is ? Is it a class with object range calling method offset ?

I need some sort of a resource to see what functionality is available but I can't make VBE do what I want.

Can someone please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you're searching for a Excel VBA tutorial; try searching Google. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow cannot provide tutorials; not because we're a bunch of meany-meanheads, but because tutorials require a level of interactivity SO simply cannot provide.

Comment: Google `excel vba tutorial`. This isn't the site to ask for a list of links to things.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194068(v=office.15).aspx.  This should help you with documentation about individual objects and their properties/methods.

As for what functionality is available:  (just about) everything you can do with the Office suite can be accessed through VBA.  A good first step is to record a macro, and then try to follow the generated code.  The *caveat* with that approach is that the recorder **LOVES** to use `.Select` and `Selection.`, which is generally bad practice.

And, when you have a specific question you can't figure out, ask it here.